# How do I recover deleted accounts on my Phantom wallet?

Tags: phantom-wallet

I have a couple of wallet addresses which I am unable to recover on my Phantom wallet. I have tried sending some SOL to those wallets so that they are not empty, reset my Phantom and tried to import wallets using recovery phrase, but those 2 specific wallets are still not showing up.

Answer (score 2):

For assistance with using Phantom please contact Phantom Support from Settings > Help & Support within your Phantom app or extension.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you must have the wrong seed phrase then. you can always try a different wallet with the same phrase to check.

Answer (score -1):

Recovering deleted accounts on a wallet, such as Phantom, can be challenging because the recovery process typically relies on the wallet's ability to import accounts using the recovery phrase. If you've already tried the recovery phrase and the accounts are not showing up, here are some additional steps you can consider:

**Check the Recovery Phrase:**
Double-check that you are entering the correct recovery phrase for the wallets you are trying to recover. Typos or errors in the recovery phrase can prevent the wallet from accurately restoring the accounts.

**Verify the Network:**
Ensure that you are connected to the correct network (e.g., mainnet, testnet).

**Wallet Software Updates:**
Ensure that your Phantom wallet is running the latest version.

**Contact Phantom Support:**
If the issue persists, consider reaching out to the Phantom wallet support team. They may be able to provide assistance or guidance on recovering deleted accounts.

**Check Transaction History:**
If you've sent SOL to the accounts in an attempt to recover them, check the transaction history on a Solana block explorer (such as SolScan). Confirm that the transactions were successful and that the SOL is associated with the correct accounts.

So with these checks, i hope it will help.